# Does a line of code run even a loop is not finished iterating yet?

Tags: javascript

As the title says.... does `function2()` run after the for loop finishes iterating or does it run even before the iteration is completed?

```
function1() {
    for () {
        <....>
    }
    this.function2();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't run concurrently with the `for` loop: it runs *after*. JS is synchronous in nature.

Comment: Yes, it does run after the `for-loop`

Comment: Just add some `console.log()`s and test it

Comment: no it doesnt run concurrently, for, while, .map(), .reduce() and many other operations are synchronouse and blocking the main thread

Comment: It will always run after the loop has finished, but within the loop asynchronous calls can be initiated that will run after after `function2` is called, making it _appear_ as if the function is called before the loop has finished.

Answer (score 2):

A simple snippet to test this:

```js
function loop(){
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    console.log(i)
  }
  function2()
}

function function2(){
  console.log('done');
}

loop();
```

So no it doesn't run before the loop is finished